# Save state of Button in activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two buttons(`button1`, `button2`) in my activty. `botton1` is 'Enabled'(true) , while the other one isn't.

When I click on `button1`, `button2` becomes 'Enabled'. I want to record this activity in this state for the next utilization of my application.

Comment: Sounds great. Would you like to ask a question other than "how can you do this" ? Can you please show any code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save state in `sharedPrefrences`, try this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Your preference name here", MODE_PRIVATE) 


b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                b2.setEnabled(true);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean("b2enabled", true).commit();//saving State here
            }
        });
```

And now where you want to use this state simple get the state as.

```
Boolean b2state= prefs.getBoolean("b2enabled", false); //false is the default value
```

And if you want to enable or disable button on result do

```
if (b2state){
b2.enabled(true);
}
else{
b2.enabled(false);
}
```

Comment: using apply(); might be better, as it is asynchronous.

Comment: What if we change it back to disabled? will it save ?

Comment: Yeah with little change we can save the state of disabled also, but the question asked for this

Comment: in this line
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();

Comment: Sorry for late reply, @jamalMassaoudi , replace that with any string name, and next time use the same string to access the shared preference

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the help of a data storage option. For a simple task like this,
shared preference is enough.
use something like this to store the state change.

```
function setState(boolean state){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref =this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("state",state);
}
```

you can retrieve the data at anytime (usually in in the beginning) like this. Note that the second argument serves the default value.

```
int state=this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("state",false);
```

Hope this helps.